# Cordova/phonegap activity lifecycle

Tags: android, google-maps, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I'm working on a map plugin for android in a cordova application (let's forget for a second that there is already more than one in the wild, and consider this an academical question), [the documentation for `MapView` states](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView.html):

> Users of this class must forward all the life cycle methods from the Activity or Fragment containing this view to the corresponding ones in this class. **[...]**

That is, I need to appropriately call on my map at least the

```
onResume()
onPause()
onDestroy()
onLowMemory()
```

methods. Is there a way to do that with Cordova/Phonegap? Keep in mind that I'm working in a subclass of `CordovaPlugin`, as with every plugin, and not in the `Activity` proper (which I cannot touch, code-wise at least).

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How silly of me: the `CordovaPlugin` class forwards the methods:

```
public void onPause(boolean multitasking)
public void onResume(boolean multitasking)
public void onDestroy()
```

among the others, which answers my question. All you need to do is implement them in the plugin and at least part of the lifecycle can be handled in this way.

As for the missing methods (`onCreate`, `onRestart`, etc), having them would make no sense, as the cordova activity is already created when whatever plugins enters the game.

Hope this helps anyone with the same problem

Comment: did you register for these events in any way? I've implemented the methods in my class extending CordovaPlugin and they're not getting called.

Answer (score 1):

Little bit clarification for Rick77's answer

In javascript file we have to mention

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
```

Then write the functions like below

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log("onDeviceReady");
}

function onPause() {
    console.log("onPause");
}

function onResume() {
    console.log("onResume");
}
```

To check the log, follow the bellow steps (While checking the log, Connect the mobile to pc and open the app)

**Step 1:** copy `chrome://inspect/#devices` and paste in chrome then you will get the page like

[image]
**Step 2:** Click on inspect

**Step 3:** Then chrome will opens the new window like

[image]

We can check the log here (Top right hand side (Marked in red color))

Comment: this is completely unrelated to OP's question. he's not asking how to send callbacks across the bridge or to bind javascript listeners. he's asking about Android lifecycle methods.