# Cordova onPause, onResume events not firing when camera or scanner being used in iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, events

I am trying to get my app to store and restore the screen that it is on, when the app switches to native camera, or to a different app. It seems to work fine for Android, but will not fire for iOS.

initialize: function() {

```
    this.bindEvents();
},

bindEvents: function() {
    console.log("Binding Events");
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    document.addEventListener('pause', this.onPause, false);
    document.addEventListener('resume', this.onResume, false);

onPause: function() {
    // Here, we check to see if we are in the middle of taking a picture. If
    // so, we want to save our state so that we can properly retrieve the
    // page url in onResume().
     window.localStorage.setItem(APP_STORAGE_KEY, window.location.href);
     console.log(window.location.href);
},

onResume: function(event) {
    // Here we check for stored state and restore it if necessary.
    setTimeout(function(){
        var storedState = window.localStorage.getItem(APP_STORAGE_KEY);

        if(storedState) {
            console.log(storedState);
            window.location.href=storedState;
        } 
    },0);
},
```

Comment: Different OS work in different ways, on Android Camera and scanner launch an intent that pauses your app, while on iOS it present a view in the app without pausing it. Anyway, on iOS you shouldn't need to restore the page, it shouldn't change when you present the camera os scanner

Comment: thanks jcesarmobile, yes onPause only seems to fire on iOS when the home button is pressed. The app requires a high volume of photos to be taken , which in turn sometimes causes the app to crash. I would like the pause and resume events to store and restore the screen the user was on , after the app is re-launched.

Comment: Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48223949/3142611). It may help